# converting list to tuple

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, continuation-passing

I have few command-line options (5 for example) and I want to convert them to tuple. The problem is that I expect them to appear in correct order, so tuple can be easily built from list using pattern-match, but in real life options can be provided in random order, so I don't know if head of the list contain Verbose option or log file name?

I tried to think how to do that using continuation-passing style, however nothing useful comes into my mind.

Is that ever possible?

I think that I can "sort" the list to have it in predicted order, but it does not look good.

Also I could get rid of the tuple and create data record - however that will still lead up to checking the type of attribute and set the correct field of the record. Still a lot of typing.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the numerous command line parsing packages on hackage?

Comment: @NathanHowell I'm using GetOpt with Permute ordering

Comment: Packages such as `cmdargs` and `optparse-applicative` fill in records fields.. ignoring the order of arguments on the command line. You might try one or both of these out as an alternative to GetOpt.

Comment: @jdevelop And what goes wrong with GetOpt? I've used that several times before with great success for just such a use case.

Comment: @DanielWagner nothing is wrong with GetOpt, it returns options as it finds them in command line. But I need to convert the list of options to tuple. Perhaps tuple isn't good choice.

Comment: @jdevelop You're right. I think you're better of with a custom options record and record syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you describe, I think you have two options.  Of the two, I would say that converting to a dictionary would be easiest, but converting to a Tuple would work and only be a little clumsy

So, take this definition:

```
options :: [OptDescr (String, String)]
options = [Option ['a'] ["alpha"] (ReqArg (\a -> ("alpha", a)) "empty") "",
           Option ['b'] ["beta"] (ReqArg (\a -> ("beta", a)) "empty") "",
           Option ['g'] ["gamma"] (ReqArg (\a -> ("gamma", a)) "empty") ""]

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let (opts, nonopts, errs) = getOpt Permute options args
    putStrLn $ show opts
```

From this, a couple of my example outputs are:

```
[("beta","b"),("alpha","a")]
[("alpha","a"),("gamma","g"),("beta","b")]
```

and so on.  Same order as on the command line.  But, because of the way I set it up above, I basically have an association list, so... if I in particular want a Tuple that has the values (alpha, beta, gamma), then my best option is...

```
(lookup "alpha" opts, lookup "beta" opts, lookup "gamma" opts)
```

You resulting data type would be (Maybe String, Maybe String, Maybe String), in the order of "alpha", "beta", and "gamma".